# Single iOS app with different UI theme depending on user

Tags: ios, themes, universal-binary

I am developing universal iOS app. This app is used by multiple clients. Depending on a client, I want to change the UI theme & colors used for icons, texts & background for view controllers. Icon color has some gradients & shadows. I know which theme & colors I need to apply depending on which user is logged in.

My question is how can I make the **SINGLE** app & apply different colors to icon & texts at runtime ? Adding same icons with multiple colors is not an option because it will increase the size of the app. I don't want to submit multiple apps on App Store with different UI themes & colors.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is really easy. You can make theme.zip file for each client which contains an xml file which defines colors and the images of button and other things related to the client. When the client log in then extract the zip file and apply the theme.

Comment: But don't you think it will increase the size of app due to multiple zip files ?

Comment: why dont you download it from the server when the client login.